# AdvancedDataGrid - Start to edit the selected row when a button is clicked

Tags: edit, advanceddatagrid, selected

I want to allow users edit Flex AdvancedDataGrid selected row by button click instead by click on AdvancedDataGrid itself. So i decide to dispatch itemEditBegin event of AdvancedDataGrid when user click a Button:

```
myADG.dispatchEvent(new AdvancedDataGridEvent(mx.events.AdvancedDataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_BEGIN,false,false,0,null,myADG.selectedIndex,null));
```

But when user click the button, edit begin always on first row of AdvancedDataGrid, whatever the myADG.selectedIndex is. And when edit ends, new value appear at the right row (that was selected). Very strange behavior. What i need to correct so that editing begin at the selected row?
I'am out of ideas, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, put this code to button click handler:

```
myADG.editedItemPosition = {rowIndex:myADG.selectedIndex, columnIndex:columnIndexYouWantToEdit};
```